# Вопрос про преобразование List в ключ Dictionary

Tags: c#, unity3d, list, словари, очередь

Нужна ваша помощь в правильном понимании этого кода. Никак его не могу понять, как не пытался. А больше всего меня интересует вот эта строка : 
 **List Move teamList = units[turnKey.Peek()];** Что она означает? Именно логику пока не могу уяснить этого действия.

```
static Dictionary<string, List<Move>> units = new Dictionary<string, List<Move>>();
static Queue<string> turnKey = new Queue<string>();
static Queue<Move> turnTeam = new Queue<Move>();


static void InitTeamTurnQueue()
{
    List<Move> teamList = units[turnKey.Peek()];

    foreach (Move unit in teamList)
    {
        turnTeam.Enqueue(unit);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Queue.Peek()
Возвращает объект, находящийся в начале очереди Queue, но не удаляет его. (копипаста с MSDN)

Потом из словарика по ключу, полученному из предыдущего шага, получают List

Далее все содержимое этого листа запихивают в turnTeam.

В целом советую почитать про Queue, Stack, Dictionary и List на MSDN.